# obsolete function remains in bash enviroment

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, bash-function

If I define a function in a bash script, e.g., envsetup.sh

```
function blabla() 
{
  echo "blabla"
}
```

then i source it by

`. envsetup.sh`

There is blabla function in my environment to use. However, if I remove this function and source it again, the blabla function is still there.

Why is it not deleted?

Comment: check what sourcing a script means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still the *same* Bash process, and running your `envsetup.sh` simply amends that process. If you invoked a new Bash shell and ran your script there, then your function wouldn't exist.

You can remove that function in your shell script thought. You can do this via:

```
unset -f blabla
```

Comment: is it possible to add such command somewhere, so that everytime when I run envsetup.sh, I reset all the functions first, then add them again?

Comment: The best place would be in `envsetup.sh` itself, so that it can clean up functions that it may have defined previously. However, the long view says that `envsetup.sh` will primarily be executed once on a clean environment, not one in which it has gone through multiple edit/source cycles.